# Is There a Way to Change the From Address in Exchange 2010 WITHOUT Using an Edge Transport?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, address

I'm setting up some general emails for my company (info@company.com and the like), so we can print flyers and such and not worry about turnover. [I'm actually using mail-enabled Public Folders, because we get charged per mailbox for spam filtering, so I'm trying to avoid adding more mailboxes. I believe the issue would be the same regardless of which solution I used].

I've given the requisite users Send As permission. My issue is that when a user replies to a message, the From is the user's email, not the one associated with the public folder. I know that I can use Address Rewriting on an Edge Transport server to change the from, but I don't have an Edge Transport server and don't really have the resources to install one. (We're a small company and I'm it for IT, except for an IT services company that isn't always too eager to do things like set up Edge Transport servers and I'm not sure what the licensing requirements are - my understanding from my brief web survey is that you need to install another copy of Exchange on a separate box with the Edge Transport role enabled, but that may not be the case for what I want to do).

And the users will squawk (and forget) if they have to change the from address when they reply to one of the emails sent to the general email address, which is my reason for this whole exercise.

So, after that much-too-long preamble, is there *any* way to rewrite a from address without using an Edge Transport server? Or do I just have to bite the bullet and install one, or train the users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup in one of my domains, and to enable such functionality I added another UPN (that is I added a secondary domain to use) at the AD level to my primary domain (You don't need to have additional Domain names to use, if you don't need that functionality, just follow the directions below.)

When you want to add a different address to a user in Exchange, select the user in Recipient Configuration in EMC, and right click, properties, and under the Email Addresses tab uncheck "Automatically update email addresses based on email address policy" (this allows you to use multiple aliases for the same account) then add another address to use, and you can choose a default address.

If I have not understood you correctly please let me know and I'm sure I can elaborate to help you solve this problem.